# ¿Por qué mi pseudo elemento no muestra el ícono de Font Awesome?

Tags: css, reactjs, font-awesome

No me muestra el ícono, le agregue `font-weight` y `font-family` asi que no sé por qué no esta funcionando, este es mi código.

```
<div className="box">
   <select className="select-css btn mr-2" onChange={ handleChange("category") }>
      <option valu="All">Pick category</option>
         { categories.map((cat, i) => (<option key={i} value={cat._id} > {cat.name}
      </option>)) 
         }
   </select>
</div>
```

Mi CSS

```
.box:before {
   font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
   font-weight: 900;
   content: '\f078';
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: ok, ya lo edite pero no se de que sirva el html en este caso.

Comment: click derecho, inspeccionar elemento, pestaña Network, revisa si font awesome está bien direccionado, es decir, si la ruta es válida. Es muy común tener errores 404 por efecto de rutas mal construidas.

Comment: Cambia `.box:before` por `.box::before`

Comment: lo cambie y sigue sin funcionar :(

Comment: uso className porque estoy usando React.

Comment: en el DOM que se visualiza?

Comment: no importa voy a buscar un tutorial de como estilizarlo mañana ahora me concentro en la funcionalidad del buscador y los filtros, gracias Jack.

Comment: Segun el codigo lo que necesitas es que aparezca el icon a lado del campo select ? o como

Comment: si el icono dentro del select

Comment: Pero dentro dentro del select para cada opcion ? o a lado del campo solamente

Comment: al lado solo en la primera opcion

Comment: y tiene que ser font-weight y font-family ? lo puedes hacer con el font normal

Comment: Prueba cambiado el Div por un `span` o un `li`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98547/discussion-between-francisco-j-blanco-and-ceciresponde).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que cambiar el `div` por un `span` ya que el **`font Awesome`** no se puede aplicar a los div

Te dejo el snippet con tres ejemplos

```css
.boxx:before {
   font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"; 
   font-weight: 900; 
   content: "\f078";


}


.box::before {
   font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free", sans-serif;
   content: "\f057";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <label>Ejemplo 3</label>
 <br>
  <span class="boxx">
    <select className="select-css btn mr-2">
    <i class="fab fa-accessible-icon">
     <option>Valor 1</option>
     <option>Valor 2</option>
      </i>
     </select>
  </span>
  
  
 <br><br>
 <label>Ejemplo 2</label>
 <br>
 <span class="box">
    <select className="select-css btn mr-2">
    <i class="fab fa-accessible-icon">
     <option>Valor 1</option>
     <option>Valor 2</option>
      </i>
     </select>
  </span>
 <br><br>
 
 
 <label>Ejemplo 3</label>
 <br>
 <i class="fab fa-angular">
  <select className="select-css btn mr-2">
     <option>Valor 1</option>
     <option>Valor 2</option>
   </select>
 </i>
 
 
 <br><br>
```